# Как в линуксе хэшировать строки из файла?

Tags: хеширование, sha256

Имеется текстовый файл с именами. Нужно захэшировать `sha256` каждую строку и вывести в консоль.

Т.е. у меня:

```
cat names.txt
Вася
Петя
```

А нужно:

```
cat names.txt | какая-то команда или скрипт
57340ec3591b399ca4bfa03bf57faf7235c753a18e4c9f8952d6acfd8ef88de4
1594d12a0e2dba6ae73d9fbc78f3db360dcca3dbb3194e15c92f9624fdb04d5b
```

Какое решение будет самым быстрым? Строк очень много (миллионы).

Этот вариант не подходит, т.к. очень медленно.

```
while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | sha256sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done < names.txt
```

Comment: Так как запускаемые программы хеширования берут весь свой ввод и строят хеш то из командной строки потребуется запуск нового процесса для каждой строки входного файла. это явно не быстро. Так что самым быстрым вариантом будет написать свой скрипт/программу, которая считает файл и посчитает сама хеш от каждой строки

Comment: https://tls.mbed.org/sha-256-source-code может сгодиться?

Comment: А как это запустить? :-)

Answer (score 0):

`while read -r; do echo $REPLY |sha256sum; done < names.txt`

Comment: Спасибо, но очень медленно

Comment: В таком случае самым быстрым будет скрипт/программа на вашем любимом языке, вероятно, с использованием OpenSSL и pthreads. Кроме того, знаю, что для перла есть Digest::SHA.